# re. Android) run an app to AndoridStudio or when you tried to install the apk app files are not visible

Tags: android, facebook, icons, manifest

After Facebook Login connect, Run app in AndroidStudio, program execution is going with device, but the file will are not be visible. I do not know why this is the case happens.

I found a solution on the Internet. but I could not apply this solution in AndroidStudio [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/finercontroloveradtbuildprocess).

Has anyone experienced the same thing ? please tell me advice. thanks

have a problem with my `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebooktest.test.facebooktest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

please read over your question ask i have no idea what your talking about , and why am seeing your manifest if your issue file not found

If its about building apk 
goto the build menu click build apk , it the same menu used to rebuild app -- clean app